# how to split a table that has 4 columns into 2 tables that have 2 columns each

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to split a table with 100 columns into 20 tables, and they are all split  by columns so for example column 1 to column 5 in one table and column 6 to 10 in the second table...etc.

I want to add for each one partition a foreign key field that can connect each partition with the other so the partitioned table will include column 1 to column 5 + a new foreign key column that can connect each partition with the next one.

Comment: Please try to build a sample table (say 4 columns) with a few records and try to explain what you need to get, by even posting the tables you want to create, their constraints and data. As is, it's hard to understand your need and help you

Answer (score 0):

You can generate two sql scripts using sql.  One to create the tables and one to copy the data into the target tables.  You have to have a primary key on the table in order to correlate the data.  PK_COLUMN_LIST is the list of primary key columns, like EMPLOYEE_ID, MANAGER_ID.  PK_COLUMN_LIST_QUOTED is the list of primary key columns but quoted, for example 'EMPLOYEE_ID','MANAGER_ID'. If you don't have a primary key, add a column and assign a sequence to each row.

```
    select 'CREATE TABLE <TABLE_NAME>'|| min(c.column_id)|| ' as select 
    <PK_COLUMN_LIST> '||listagg(column_name,',')within group(order by c.column_id ) 
     ||' from <TABLE_NAME> where 1=0;'
    from user_tab_columns c where table_name = '<TABLE_NAME>'
    and c.COLUMN_NAME  not in (<PK_COLUMN_LIST_QUOTED>)
    group by mod(c.COLUMN_ID, 20);
```

```
    select 'INSERT ALL' from dual
    union all
    select  ' INTO <TABLE_NAME>'|| min(c.column_id)|| ' (  <PK_COLUMN_LIST>'||
    listagg(column_name,',')within group(order by c.column_id ) 
    || ') values ( <PK_COLUMN_LIST> ,'||  listagg(column_name,',')within group(order by c.column_id )    ||' )'
    from user_tab_columns c where table_name = '<TABLE_NAME>'
    and c.COLUMN_NAME  not in (<PK_COLUMN_LIST_QUOTED>)
    group by mod(c.COLUMN_ID, 20)
    union all select 
    'select t.* from <TABLE_NAME> t' from dual;
```

The output of these sql statements can be run in a script, or if you need to automate the process you can select into variables and execute immediate or use dbms_sql.